# ___int___ method missing from Built in Class in Python

Tags: python, type-conversion

When I call `int("1")`, I get `1`. But when I call `"1".__int__()` I get an error. I checked the methods of the class str, and there really is no method  `__int__`. This confuses me, because then I do not understand how `int("1")` is able to return anything at all! It shouldn't work either, but it does. How can you explain this?

Comment: `int` can interpret strings, but `str` doesn't have all possible methods for anything that a string might contain, because that would be *a lot*.

Answer (score 2):

Similarly it does not have a `__float__` or `__decimal__` or any other dedicated method for every single way to initialize an integer. This design would not make sense as it is neither extendable nor scalable.

And why would a string type care about converting a string to anything else? that is the "target"'s type/class problem to handle.

Instead, the `int` type/class's initializer knows how to handle different, relevant types.

I believe your confusion stems from the custom class's datamodel, by which one should implement `__int__` in order to support passing an instance to `int(...)`.

This makes sense because there is no way for Python's built-in types to "re-write" themselves when a custom class is defined.